# How to get this work Div addClass

Tags: php, javascript

I try to make this work but not luck yet, why the DIV does not highlight(Flashing) when the figures updated in stats.php?

In stats.php

```
<div id="student_today"><b>$<?php print getTodayStats($collageid); ?></b></div>
Month:
<div id="student_month"><b>$<?php print getMonthStats($collageid); ?></b></div>
```

Below style for div:

```
.stats_highlight{
background: #03B1EE;
border-top-color: #03B1EE;
z-index: 10;
color: #fff;
```

In main.php :

```
                      <tr class="live">
                    <td width="267">
                      <p align="left">Today's Students:</p></td>
                    <td width="201">
                      <p align="left">&nbsp;</p></td>
                    <td width="220">
                      <span value="value" id="student_today"></span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="live">
                    <td width="267">
                      <p align="left">Month's students:</p></td>
                    <td width="201">
                      <p align="left">&nbsp;</p></td>
                    <td width="220">
                      <span class="value" id="student_month"></span></td>
                  </tr>
```

I need someone who can guide me solve this question. Really appreciate.

Comment: hello, it should be work like fade in fade out every time stats updated in database.

Comment: hello, someone here can guide me how to get javascript addClass in  <span class="value"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question:

> hello, someone here can guide me how to get javascript addClass in
>    ?

The answer using jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('newClass').removeClass('initialClass');
});
```

​See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/YCst4/398/).

You will need to click on `'Some text here'` (SPAN content); than jQuery will replace initialClass with `newClass`.
..

**EDIT:**

Below is for your initial question (in regards with your comments):

Live **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/YCst4/398/)**

Now, that was in case you needed to fade out; replace the class and fade in. If you need it without class replacement than it would be even with less code. Please feel free to play with the demo.

Comment: Thanks. I try it, nice. Can you please look into my post above.

Comment: @farisha Please check the addition and let us know if it works for you. If you find my answer acceptable please mark it by selecting green check mark so the other users could find it easier.

Comment: WorkS great! I Love stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I may have over cooked it ,but this will work

```
setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#messagebox").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                        $("#messagebox").addClass("messageboxcss");
                        });
                        }, 1000); 


setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#messagebox").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $("#messagebox").removeClass("messageboxcss");
                        });
                        }, 2000);
```

​

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UUdTs/1/)

Comment: Thanks there. better than top there . Can you please look into my post above.